# Facebook Audience Network with dfp mediation network

Tags: google-dfp, facebook-audience-network

### App

It already uses dfp to get ads from admob as described in [DFP Android Guides](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner). Now I want to get ads from facebook audience network through dfp. I follow the [guide here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/mediation-networks) and add `FacebookAdapter.jar` and `AudienceNetwork.jar` into my app.

### DFP

In my line item, I set type `price priority` and use `sdk mediation` ad with facebook audience network.

### Condition

However, when the app runs, I see the following message just like someone else reported [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/facebookadapter/google-admob-ads-sdk/MWoBWBR0FQM/nDrPe-kMbfIJ).

`W/FacebookAdapter(18649): The input ad size is not supported at this moment.`

I think the code works, and dfp delivers the ads from facebook audience network. I am pretty sure about this because both dfp and facebook console show the ad request information.

### Questions

1. Do I setup the line item correctly?
2. How could we fix the issue of unsupported ad size?

---

### Update

1. Nothing wrong about the line item setting. But if you use dfp for mediation, you need to be aware of the priority [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177279?hl=en)
2. Currently, the simplest solution is to give up smart banner and use banner instead. This would allow you to get mediation ad from facebook audience network.
3. Don't forget to add `-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.** {*;}` if you use proguard. Otherwise, you will see couldn't instantiate facebook adapter message.

Comment: Hi.. I want to integrate facebook audience network  with mediation service. How can i achieve this . please help me. Do i need to create custom adapter class for this or how to add facebook adapter in networkExtras() bundle.

Comment: And the setup for interstitial mediation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823274/dfp-ads-setting-up-facebook-audience-mediation-for-interstitial-ads-adunit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use dfp sdk so if you use other sdk, I cannot guarantee it works. My code already works for admob and other mediation network, and I try to add facebook audience network.

**layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

Note that I use **BANNER** instead of **SMART_BANNER** here, somehow, the banner size is incompatible between dfp and facebook. In my opinion, this is an issue of sdk. I hope google would fix this later, but I just give up SMART_BANNER for now. As I mentioned in the update, if you use SMART_BANNER, you will get this `W/FacebookAdapter(18649): The input ad size is not supported at this moment.`

**jar**

[facebook android sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip) - This one is from facebook, and you can find the `AudienceNetwork.jar` in it.

[facebook adapter](https://dl.google.com/dl/googleadmobadssdk/adapterfacebookandroid.zip) - This is from [dfp mediation network](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/mediation-networks), and you can find FacebookAdapter.jar.

In Android Studio, all you need to do is put jars in your libs folder and make sure your build.gradle includes the libs folder.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
...
}
```

[image: Project Structure in Android Studio]

Somehow, when I build the apk, the libraries are not compiled even when I `Synchronize 'build.gradle'`. Hence, you might want to check your project.iml and make sure you see the following in it.

**project.iml**

```
...
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="AudienceNetwork" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="FacebookAdapter" level="project" />
```

**Proguard**

As I said in the reply, you must not forget to add `com.google.ads.mediation` if you use Proguard! Otherwise, you will keep seeing cannot `instantiate com.google.ads.mediation.facebookadapter class`.

```
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.** { public *; }
```

**Log**

This is the message you will see if everything is configured properly.

`02-18 16:24:25.315    8081-8307/com.xxxxxxx I/Ads﹕ Trying mediation network: 1.0568273599589929E19
02-18 16:24:25.320    8081-8081/com.xxxxxxx I/Ads﹕ Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter
02-18 16:24:25.335    8081-8081/com.xxxxxxx W/Ads﹕ Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}`

**This is the simplest way to use Audience Network if you are willing to give up SMART BANNER.** If you must use SMART BANNER, I suggest you to implement custom event banner using `com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventBanner` yourself. In [Vpon's Google Admob Mediation](http://wiki.vpon.com/index.php?title=SDK4_English_AdMob), it shows an example of implementation of custom evener banner. I think you will be able to use SMART_BANNER in this way, and it also means that you have to convert the ad size yourself.

---

### Update

**Targeting**

I am actually not sure about if you can do targeting with facebook audience network or not because I cannot find anything about targeting in facebook's official document.

You can see [dfp](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner) Custom targeting for this, and I **guess** the code would be something like `.addNetworkExtrasBundle(new com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter(), bundle)`.

**Placement id**

In case you're not familiar with how to use placement_id you get from facebook audience network, you have to do the following things:

1. Create a line order
2. Create a line item
3. Create a `SDK mediation` creative
4. Select **Facebook Audience Network** like the image below and put your placement id there.

[image]

This is the very simple version of how you do it, and you should know that the setting of line item will have effects on ads. If you settings are not correct, for example, the item's **type** priority is too low or **frequency capping** is too long, you might not see the ads.

---

### Feb 2016

You can use gradle to install audience network library now.

`compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'`

More information at [Using the Native Ad API in Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/native-api)

If you see the following messages without delivering any ad, that is probably because you don't have facebook app installed on your device or emulator.

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider 
W/FacebookAdapter: No fill. We are not able to serve ads to this person. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. If you are integrating Audience Network for the first time, you can use test ads https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing.
```

---

### May 2016

Yoann Hercouet points out in the comments that `LARGE_BANNER is also not available on Facebook`.

Comment: can you please help me with fb audience network and medaition service. I have used publisher ad view in my code but unable to follow the process explained on google mediation page. I am unable to pass value in .addNetworkExtras() in ad request. how to use facebook adapter and placement id here.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner see custom targeting for addNetworkExtras()

Comment: You don't really need to add anything about facebook adapter in your code,  you just have to import the jar correctly. I think the publisher ad view in sdk does the rest for you. When you get the placement id from facebook audience network, you will have to create line order, line order, and creatives for the order. You will need to choose medation when creating a creative, and select network `Facebook Audience Network` in the mediation.

Comment: thnks for your quick repsonse! but what will be the key for placement id and addNetworkExtras(new AdMobExtras(bundle)) in this line what the changes i need to make, I want to use fb audience network or ads but i didn't get any class to pass in addNetworkExtras

Comment: ohk.. i will create a line order and creative . can you please pass me a link for that. and do i need to pass my placement id there?

Comment: I think it would be like `.addNetworkExtrasBundle(new com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter(), bundle)` for network extras. But I do warn you that I haven't done this myself, you will have to try it yourself. Besides, I don't see anything about targeting in facebook's official document unlike admob's which provides targeting example code.

Comment: ok. thanks for help.! i'll try it this way too. What about the line items and creatives. Can i do it by simply creating a line item too?

Comment: hey thanks for the help.. seems to be working.. but when i have created a line item and order getting this status " Inactive Needs creatives" i have created a creative for this line item but statis is still inactive what i need to do to make it active

Comment: ohh finally somehow i managed to get rady status for my order but it is not in "delivering" status what i need to do for this

Comment: You need to approve your line item. You should do some tests with dfp first so you understand how it works.

Comment: ok thanks. one more concern if i have multiple orders in dfp then how my app will recognize the correct one. where i need to pass the order id or creative id in the code.

Comment: You can use multiple orders, items or creatives, but what creative your app gets depends on all your setting in line order and line item. You can even use multiple mediation creative with the same placement_id, that all depends on you. And you won't be able to pass any order or creative id because the only id you pass into your app is the ad unit id you get from dfp. So I suggest you do some experiments on dfp settings.

Comment: i get ad unit id and set all creatives and other things perfectly on my dfp account but the concern is that status is still ready. what i need to do in case to change this

Comment: Have you created placement for your line item? You also have to create placement in the inventory of dfp and bind the placement and ad unit together, otherwise, your ad will not be delivered. The status will be ready and not delivering if any configuration is incorrect.

Comment: @cwhsu FYI LARGE_BANNER is also not available on Facebook

Comment: @YoannHercouet Thank you, I have updated your comment in the post.

Answer (score 0):

there is a adsize matching issue inside the FacebookAdapter:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/MWoBWBR0FQM

Comment: In my post, I already include this link, so I know what they did. However, there is a big difference between their situation and mine. Somehow they use `com.facebook.ads.AdSize`, but you cannot use facebook ad size in the PublisherAdView. I know the problem is ad size, but the post is not very helpful.