# DFP ads - Setting up Facebook Audience mediation for interstitial ads (AdUnit + LineItem + creative)

Tags: android, ios, google-dfp, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

Im trying to setup the DFP side of FBA interstitial mediation, i.e. create the necessary AdUnit + LineItem + creative.

I didn't find any example for FBA. When I choose "interstitial" as the adsize, I can not choose mediation for the creative:

[image: Can't add creative die to size restrictions]

I've already successfuly set up my client app (Android + iOS) for Facebook Audience ad mediation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no tutorial for FBA, but I've found this tutorial for VPON that seems to be applicable for FBA as well: http://vpon-sdk.github.io/android/mediation/dfp/

The result:

[image]

---

**On the client side**:

Android:

1. First implement the DFP SDK:
   https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/quick-start
2. Then add the mediation library and adapter:
   https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/mediation#include_network_adapters_and_sdks
3. And finally update your manifest as per Facebook's instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/interstitial

iOS:

1. First implement the DFP SDK:
   https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start
2. Then add the mediation library and adapter: 
   https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/mediation